# How to add image layer in dot spatial

Tags: c#, dotspatial

I am a c# programmer.I need to work on shape files so i am using dot spatial plugin.There is a class FeatureSet through which i give FeatureType of point,line,polygon but there is no image type to add image layer.So please help me how to add image layer

Answer (score 1):

Do you use this code:

```
map.AddLayer("pathToImageFile");
```

or:

```
IImageData i = ImageData.Open("pathToImageFile");
IMapImageLayer ly = map1.Layers.Add(i);
```

Also refer to [Loading a shapefile and image using DotSpatial](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257009/loading-a-shapefile-and-image-using-dotspatial)